# Excel VBA replace/substitue module

Tags: vba, excel, replace, substitution

I'm using a custom function called ColorFunction which I found on the internet to sum the values in a range of cells if the background colour is the same as another cell.

This is what is in the cell that shows the total.

```
=ColorFunction($AE$3,$B$3:$W$3,TRUE)
```

And the ColorFunction is as below.

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult
lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex
If SUM = True Then
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
        End If
    Next rCell
Else
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = 1 + vResult
        End If
    Next rCell
End If
ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

This all works fine. However some of the values I'm using there is an * in them after the number value. For my other cells that I sum up these values in I use the following.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(0&SUBSTITUTE(B3:W3,"*","")))
```

Is there any way I can do this with the ColorFunction to ignore the * in the cells when summing up the cells with a colour in them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vResult = vResult + Val(0 & Replace(rCell.Text, "*", vbNullString))
```

Alternately, if the first part of the cell is the number, you could just use Val

```
vResult = vResult + Val(rCell.Text)
```

Comment: Cheers. I used the following 



down voteunaccept 


vResult = vResult + Val(0 & Replace(rCell.Text, "*", vbNullString)) 

and it works great

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the code as below by adding the REPLACE function (`vba.Replace(rCell, "*", "")`:

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult
lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex
If SUM = True Then
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(replace(rCell,"*",""), vResult)
        End If
    Next rCell
Else
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = 1 + vResult
        End If
    Next rCell
End If
ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```